# Find General Path Inscribed in Polygon

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math, geometry

I'm trying to write an algorithm in C# that takes the points around a polygon and finds some sort of directional path inside of it. I've already looked into the funnel algorithm and some other pathfinding approaches but still a bit confused on how to implement such process.

Below I have a picture that demonstrates what I'm trying to do.

[image]

Comment: What is your question? I do a lot of pathfinding work.

Comment: I ask because there are a myriad of ways to find a path. One could even just take your start/end points, draw lines from each to a boundary point, and then walk the contour in one direction til you hit the other line.

Comment: Do you want a shortest path? Do you want a path that tries to stay centered from the boundary? Do you have holes? Is your geometry dynamic? How many paths do you need to find and from what source/destinations? Are your sources points or can they also be polygons (e.g. buildings)? Do your units have radii? etc. This actually can become a very complicated question akin to "how do I make a 3d engine" depending on the scope.

Comment: Yeah good point! So to clarify the geometry is dynamic as it does grow in size as well as I want the path to stay centered relative to its closet boundary. To give more context I'm working on an application using AR Foundation that takes scan data and develops a 2D closed polygon to represent a flat plane in 3D space. The idea is to scan a continuous surface and instantiate objects along the path as it grows.

Comment: Take a look at [Straight Skeletons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straight_skeleton), particularly the applications to area collapse and finding [centerlines](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Area-Collapse-and-Road-Centerlines-based-on-Haunert-Sester/8b3a59984ca395ceba92cbff2da22a737f74f119).

Comment: Sweet thank you. I check that out for sure it looks to be the closest thing to what I am trying to accomplish.